# Multiple list comprehension into single list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to change the values of a list using list comprehension I can do that by using 3 list comprehensions

```
clr = [1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3]
clr= ["green"  if i== 1 else i for i in clr]
clr = ["yellow"  if i==2 else i for i in clr]
clr = ["black"  if i == 3 else i for i in clr]
```

where as using the below mentioned code is throwing syntax error

```
clr = ["green"  if i== 1 else "yellow"  if i==2 else "black"  if i == 3 for i in clr]
```

Is there any better way to do it??

Comment: You didn't say what error is being thrown. You should always include the full traceback in your question when asking about errors! Anyway, you forgot the final `else` part: `... else "black"  if i == 3 else i for i in clr]`. But Willem's solution is better.

Comment: I really do not like that you have code like this `clr = [... for i in clr]` and that you never provide the initial value of `clr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can for instance **define a dictionary**:

```
the_dic = { 1 : 'green', 2 : 'yellow', 3 : 'black' }
```

and then perform a **mapping** like:

```
clr = [the_dic.get(i,i) for i in clr]
```

Or by using `map(..)` (in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) this works as a generator (thus lazily):

```
clr = map(the_dic.get,clr)
```

This will insert `None`s in case the element in `clr` is not in the dictionary.

This will thus add `i` to the `clr` list, if it is *not* in the dictionary. This is beause we use `the_dic.get(i,i)`. The first `i` is the *key* we lookup in the dictionary. The second `i` is the "fallback" value: the value we return in case the key is not found.

In case you want to **filter these out**, you can use:

```
clr = [the_dic[i] for i in clr if i in the_dic]
```

Comment: `map(the_dic.get, clr)` also works in place of a list comprehension, although it less gracefully handles errors.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: given every element in `clr` has a key in the dictionary, yes. Or a bit shorter: `map(the_dic.get,clr)`.

Comment: Yeah, I reduced to that while you were editing I think :) My original suggestion, `map(lambda x: the_dic[x], clr)` does have one potential advantage, being it throws a `KeyError` for invalid elements in clr... so I probably should have left it. Either way, this is absolutely the right approach, regardless of the method chosen to translate the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    colors = collections.defaultdict(int,{ 1:'green', 2:'yellow', 3:'black' })
    clr = [ colors[i] for i in clr ]
```

You could add `if 1 <= i <= 3 condition` to the list comprehension if it is important not to put the extraneous 0's in the output.  In that case you could use an ordinary dict instead of a defaultdict.

Comment: Thanks I will look in to collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this within list comprehension:

```
[("green"  if i == 1 else ("yellow" if i == 2 else "black")) for i in clr]
```

and if you want to skip over values that are neither 1, 2, or 3:

```
[("green"  if i == 1 else ("yellow" if i == 2 else "black")) for i in clr if i in range(1, 4)]
```

and if you want to leave the values not in [1, 2, 3] unchanged do this:

```
[("green"  if i == 1 else ("yellow" if i == 2 else ("black" if i == 3 else i))) for i in clr]
```

Comment: Thanks AGN Gazer this seems to me the easiest way of doing what I wanted.

Comment: @SwamyYmln This may be the easiest for you, but this would be awful to maintain.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Maybe. But this answer addresses the title "Multiple list comprehension into *single list comprehension*" of this question.

Comment: Ah, I view that as a prime example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344593).

Comment: @TemporalWolf I disagree. A *simple* oneliner `["green"  if i == 1 else "yellow" if i == 2 else "black" for i in clr]` is no more difficult to maintain than a dict + list comprehension [the dict solution is elegant though]. Moreover, this solution shows that what user wants is achievable with list comprehension.

Comment: `[["green", "yellow", "black"][x-1] for x in clr]` solves the issue if there are no other values (it will throw an `IndexError` for any other value, or act strangely). But I wouldn't recommend that for anything other than a hack job. The moment you start addressing corner cases or adding more you'll likely encounter issues.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I do not find your solution (above) to be a bad solution. How can you like the solution of @WillemVanOnsem and not like this solution? The only difference is that it uses lists instead of dictionaries! If you do not like the list solution, let me post it as an answer. Of course the list should be created only once and not in the loop but once some optimization is performed such as `clrn = [ None, 'green', 'yellow', 'black' ]; clr = [clrn[i] for i in clr]` this code is about 4x times faster than @WillemVanOnsem solution based on dictionaries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149260/discussion-between-temporalwolf-and-agn-gazer).