# Is it possible to declare multiple list comprehensions in a single list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

I am learning python for customizing an application which uses Ironpython 2.7.4.
My inputs are as follows:

```
nids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
enids = [1,2,2,8,3,4,5,5,6,7,7]
s = [44, 33, 68, 76, 43, 43, 53, 55, 69, 45, 31]
t = [50, 40, 30, 10, 10, 60, 50, 80, 90, 10, 30]
```

I want elements from enids which are in nids. Also I want elements from s and t at the index of elements from enids which are in nids. I came up with following list comprehensions:

```
enids = [enid for enid in enids if enid in nids]
s = [s[i] for i, enid in enumerate(enids) if enid in nids]
t = [t[i] for i, enid in enumerate(enids) if enid in nids]
```

Since all the above list comprehension uses same for and if conditions I wonder if there is any way to simplify the code and save computation time.

Comment: could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091415/multiple-list-comprehension-into-single-list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Examine:

```
all = [(enid, s[i], t[i]) for i,enid in enumerate(enids) if enid in nids]
```

it gives similar results, but in tuple:

```
(1, 44, 50),
 (2, 33, 40),
 (2, 68, 30),
 (3, 43, 10),
 (4, 43, 60),
 (5, 53, 50),
 (5, 55, 80),
 (6, 69, 90)]
```